# Swift: Tabbar cannot be hidden with imagePickerController

Tags: swift, tabbar

People please help I am desperate... :-(

I am having a tabbar with 4 items....I will execute this to get modal view over the tabbar.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1
let modal = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewTripVC") as! NewTripVC
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modal)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In that modal I have an image view that can contain a photo...I am picking the image from photo library with image picker

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum){
   self.imagePicker.delegate = self
   self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum;
   self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
   self.imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
   self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And then I am using this for closing....but when the view is closed...tab bar will popup and I can't hide it :-(

```
//this will dismiss the view but also will show tabBar that can't be hidden with any way
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I tried this... but this does not working...:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1
```

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to put self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1 inside the completion block of imagepicker dismiss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is very simple. Change

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
```

To this.....so lame

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
```